# why angular service attribute changes can not affect the relative value in the controller scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

**Here is my code brief:**

**controller:**

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, EssayRsc, EssaySvc) {
    $scope.pageInfo = EssaySvc;
}
```

**service:**

```
angular.module('testApp').service('EssaySvc', function (EssayRsc, $document, $rootScope) {
    var count = 1;
    var essayList = [{title:11111},{title:11111},{title:11111},{title:11111},{title:11111},{title:11111},{title:11111}];
    var pageNum = null;
    var pages = null;

    $document.scroll(function () {

        if ($document.height() == ($document.scrollTop() + angular.element(window).height())) {

        EssayRsc.get({pageSize:count}, function (resp) {
            essayList = essayList.concat(resp.list);
            pageNum = resp.pageNum;
            pages = resp.pages;
            this.essayList = essayList;

            // this changes here but not changes in the controller
            console.log(this.essayList);
        });

    }
});

    this.essayList = essayList;
    this.pageNum = pageNum;
    this.pages = pages;
})
```

**html:**

```
 <ul class="no-bullet" ng-repeat="essay in pageInfo.essayList">
                        <li class="essay-query-li" ng-click="viewEssay(essay.id)"><a href="#">{{essay.title}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**This is my question:**

I want to set a listener in a service,so erverytime I scroll to the bottom of the window it can load one record.

but everytime essayList attribute in the service changed,but in the controller and view it never change, i really cannot figure out why and how to solve it,if you know the answer please tell me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `EssayRsc.get` angular aware (i.e., does it use `$http` or any such angular service which knows about `$digest` loops)? Otherwise, you may have to trigger one manually with `$rootScope.$apply()` in your callback to `EssayRsc.get` function. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: angular.module('testApp').factory('EssayRsc', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('../../essay/:id', {}, {update: {method: 'put'}});
})

Comment: I don't know where should i put the code $rootScope.$apply() in,I tried put in the  EssayRsc.get call back function but not work and threw an error,please say it precisely,thanks!